# How to integrate the generated lexer/parser from Antlr4 into my java project

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

please bear with me I'm not a coding expert.

I built a grammar in ANTLR4 using ANTRWorks 2. I tested the grammar with various teststrings and it works fine within there. Now what I'm having trouble with is using the generated lexer and parser in my own code. As code generation target I'm using Java.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
String s = "query(std::map .find(x) == y): bla";
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(s);
TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(new pqlcLexer(input)); 

pqlcParser parser = new pqlcParser(tokens); 
ParseTree tree = parser.query();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree());
```

The Output of that is just "query", which is my starting rule. I would expect something like the output from ANTLRworks: 
"(query (quant_expr query ( (match std::map . find ( (cm x) ) == (cm (numeral 256))) ) : (query (qexpr bla))))"
Here is the tree visually: http://puu.sh/94Nlx/00dc35bb05.png

Which methods do I have to call to get the proper syntax tree as output?

Here is the generated Parser for reference: http://pastebin.com/Lb34TyRW and the grammar:

```
// Lexer

//Schlüsselwörter
EXISTS: 'exists';
REDUCE: 'reduce';
QUERY: 'query';
INT: 'int';
DOUBLE: 'double';
CONST: 'const';
STDVECTOR: 'std::vector';
STDMAP: 'std::map';
STDSET: 'std::set';

INTEGER_LITERAL  : (DIGIT)+ ;
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
DOUBLE_LITERAL : DIGIT '.' DIGIT+;

LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
LBRACK          : '[';
RBRACK          : ']';
DOT             : '.';
EQUAL           : '==';
LE              : '<=';
GE              : '>=';
GT              : '>';
LT              : '<';
ADD             : '+';
MUL             : '*';
AND             : '&&';
COLON           : ':';

IDENTIFIER    :   JavaLetter JavaLetterOrDigit*;
fragment JavaLetter    :   [a-zA-Z$_]; // these are the "java letters" below 0xFF
fragment JavaLetterOrDigit    :   [a-zA-Z0-9$_]; // these are the "java letters or digits" below 0xFF
WS  
    :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip  
    ;
COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;


// Parser

//start_rule: query;

query :
      quant_expr
      | qexpr+
      | IDENTIFIER // order IDENTIFIER and qexpr+?
      | numeral
      //| c_expr TODO

      ;

c_type : INT | DOUBLE | CONST;
bin_op: AND | ADD | MUL | EQUAL | LT | GT | LE| GE;


qexpr:
         LPAREN query RPAREN bin_op_query? 
         // query bin_op query
         | IDENTIFIER  bin_op_query? // copied from query to resolve left recursion problem
         | numeral bin_op_query?  // ^
         | quant_expr bin_op_query? // ^
           // query.find(query)
         | IDENTIFIER  find_query? // copied from query to resolve left recursion problem
         | numeral find_query?  // ^
         | quant_expr find_query?
           // query[query]
          | IDENTIFIER  array_query? // copied from query to resolve left recursion problem
         | numeral array_query?  // ^
         | quant_expr array_query?

     // | qexpr bin_op_query // bad, resolved by quexpr+ in query 
     ;

bin_op_query: bin_op query bin_op_query?; // resolve left recursion of query bin_op query

find_query: '.''find' LPAREN query RPAREN;
array_query: LBRACK query RBRACK;

quant_expr:
    quant id ':' query
          | QUERY LPAREN match RPAREN ':' query
          | REDUCE LPAREN IDENTIFIER RPAREN id ':' query
    ;

match:
         STDVECTOR LBRACK id RBRACK EQUAL cm
     | STDMAP '.''find' LPAREN cm RPAREN EQUAL cm
     | STDSET '.''find' LPAREN cm RPAREN
     ;

cm:
    IDENTIFIER
  | numeral
  // | c_expr TODO
  ;

quant :
          EXISTS;

id :
     c_type IDENTIFIER
     | IDENTIFIER // Nach Seite 2 aber nicht der Übersicht. Laut übersicht id -> aber dann wäre Regel 1 ohne +
   ;

numeral :
            INTEGER_LITERAL
        | DOUBLE_LITERAL
        ;
```

Comment: I tried to step through the parser doing its magic a bit.

It seems to match 'query' to IDENTIFIER, when it's a keyword and it should match to quant_expr instead. More tokens don't even get looked at. Is the Lexer having problems and thus the Parser can't work properly? I don't understand this since the parsing works just fine in Antlrworks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the fact that Java Classes should start with an uppercase letter (so you should rename your grammar, so it starts with an uppercase letter) your last line should be

```
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

to print the tree. Otherwise the tree doesnÄt know which parser to use and only outputs what you described.

**EDIT**

When naming your grammar `PQLC` the following code

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String query = "query(std::map .find(x) == y): bla";
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(query);
        PQLCLexer lexer = new PQLCLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        PQLCParser parser = new PQLCParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.query(); // begin parsing at query rule
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree
    }
}
```

produces this output with ANTLR v4.2 at my machine:

```
(query (quant_expr query ( (match std::map . find ( (cm x) ) == (cm y)) ) : (query (qexpr bla))))
```

Comment: And I got it working. I hate myself...
I used (very) old parser and lexer files. ANTLRWorks had put the generated classes into the temp folder instead of the folder where the grammar was.